# Simple Openlayers + Angular

Tags: angularjs, openlayers

i'm trying to implement simple openlayers map using angular

```
var app =angular.module('app',[] );

app.controller= ('myController',function() {

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()]
    });

    if (!map.getCenter()) {
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
    return map;
}
```

I can't find solution for this error :

Uncaught Error:

[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

***What am i doing wrong?***

Comment: This seems to be some kind of dependency injection problem have a look at this fiddle there it is working maybe you missed something http://jsfiddle.net/tianhai/r4w5r/

Comment: this "jsfiddle.net/tianhai/r4w5r –  stackg91"     is angular 1.1 version.
I'm using 1.3 and this example  doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 0):

`app.controller` is a function.

Here is the good syntax :

```
app.controller('myController',function() {

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()]
    });

    if (!map.getCenter()) {
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
    // return map; <- this should not be done. I don't understand what you're trying to do with a controller
});
```

In angular, controllers are used to bind data and functions to your html view. A controller is not a function that you call to get a result returned. You call functions that are defined into your controller. eg:

```
angular.module("app", []);
angular.module('app').controller('someController', function(){
    var self = this;

    self.hello = "World";

    self.alertMe = function(){
        alert("HELLO");
    };
});
```

and the html :

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="someController as example" 
        ng-click="example.alertMe()">
            Hello {{example.hello}} 
   </div>
</body>
```

Will have as result :

```
Hello World
```

and if you click on it, it will open an alert.

Comment: wow. Thank u very much for this exhaustive answer. Now i understand better Controller's idea.
But according to my true problem ,this new proposal without ''return map'' still does not work....